how to download multiple files matching a glob pattern from a public ftp server
I'm hoping to download all the *.csv files from https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/pmc/oa_bulk/oa_comm/xml/
I can grab the one by one by using something like
curl -O https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/pmc/oa_bulk/oa_comm/xml/oa_comm_xml.PMC000xxxxxx.baseline.2024-06-18.filelist.csv

Is there a way to do that on the command line, or alternately, I could write a quick script to grab them all one by one like that if I had a programmatic way of getting the listing from the directory. So is there an easy way to get the listing?
I thought I might be able to do it on the ftp command line when I try to ftp directly to ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov it wants a password which I don't have.

This question is similar to: How to download files matching a particular pattern from ftp command line. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The process is sample with ftp client. You enter:
ftp ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov

for username enter
anonymous

for password
no@no.no

then
cd /pub/pmc/oa_bulk/oa_comm/xml

then
mget *.csv

Here if you get question like:
[anpqy?]

press a for all. The other way is before mget command type prompt to avoid questions.
and at the end
quit

This work on every ftp client (Windows, Linux, not tested on Mac, but for sure will work).

It might be worth noting, that the "anonymous" login usually takes any password, but usually the FTP server asks you to "send your complete email address as your password".

@mpy, I usually use -m@, - (dash) is used to suppress some messages from the server (disable verbose mode), RFC 1635 :)

I got a [anpqy?] prompt and correctly guessed that a would get me "all" but it would be great to add that to the answer. :)

@PurpleVermont, will add it. And will add also another way to avoid this message at all :)
